# Can i find the value of trigonometry functions in this case?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, complex-numbers

If $\sin x=2$ then what is the value of $x$?
I know this is impossible in real numbers because maximum and minimum value of $\sin x$ is $1$ and $-1$ respectively.
but in imaginary number we can find it.

Comment: You've answered you're own question. There is no real number $x$ such that $\sin(x)=2$.

Comment: I know there are no possible real numbers but is it possible in imaginary number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by writing what $\sin$ is in complex numbers:
$$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
From here use $z=e^{ix}$. Then you get 
$$z-\frac 1z=4i$$
Multiply with $z$ and you get a quadratic. Solve it and take the logarithm.